# Rails app working with nginx locally, but redirecting 301 when deployed to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elb

I have a dockerized Rails app, and the nginx container with some custom config on runtime that I have setup. The setup works perfectly fine on my local machine.

I fire up docker-compose and the nginx container pointing to the app network, everything works like a charm. I'm able to access the app at localhost instead of localhost:8000.

However, I'm currently deploying this on AWS ECS and there's a loadbalancer with HTTPS involved here.

The app gets deployed and both containers are running fine, but urls that I hit are returning a 301 Moved Permanently.

Here's my default.conf

```
upstream PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME {
  server PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME:PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_PORT;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.PLACEHOLDER_VHOST;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;
  server_name PLACEHOLDER_VHOST;

  root /PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME/public;

  # level due to Rail's asset pipeline.
  
  location ~ ^/assets/ {
    gzip_static on;

    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
  }



  location ~ /\. {
    return 404;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }

  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    try_files /favicon.ico = 204;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
  }


  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;";


  location @PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    
    proxy_pass http://PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME;
  }
}
```

and here's my script that I'm running when the container starts :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME="my-api"
PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_PORT="8000"


PLACEHOLDER_VHOST="$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)"


DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH="/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"

sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER_VHOST/${PLACEHOLDER_VHOST}/g" "${DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH}"
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME/${PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_NAME}/g" "${DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH}"
sed -i "s/PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_PORT/${PLACEHOLDER_BACKEND_PORT}/g" "${DEFAULT_CONFIG_PATH}"

# Execute the CMD from the Dockerfile and pass in all of its arguments.
exec "$@"
```

I even tried setting PLACEHOLDER_VHOST in the script to my ELB public DNS but to no avail. What could be the issue here?